# Subfigure label position and visibility in memoir

Tags: memoir, subfloats

I am writing my master thesis using Memoir. I want all subfigures to have their labels in the top left corner. I have so far done this with tikz, but I would like to find a more elegant solution as my current solution has flaws.

I would like to be able to automatically reference figures in the text, without having to manually specify the subfigure. This means each figure needs to have a label. Yet if I label the subfigure, said label invariably appears underneath the figure, and I am not sure how to move it, change its color and so on.

Anyway, an mwe and images of current and desired solution:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz,siunitx,mwe}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\newcommand{\scalebarimg}[6]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw node[name=micrograph] {\includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#1}}; %I fetch the image
    \draw[ultra thick,#6] (micrograph.south west)++(0.03*0#2\textwidth,0.035*0#2\textwidth)--++(#2*#3\textwidth,0)node[above,midway]{#4 \si{\micro\meter}}; %I draw the scalebar
    \draw  (micrograph.north west)  node[anchor=north west,yshift=-1,#6]{\textbf{\small{(#5)}}}; %I draw the image label
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subbottom[\label{fig:one}]{
    \scalebarimg{example-image}{.45}{0.33933}{50}{a}{black}
}\subbottom[\label{fig:two}]{
    \scalebarimg{example-image}{.45}{0.33933}{50}{b}{white}
}
\caption{Figures (a) and (b) should not be doubly labeled.}
\end{figure}



See Figure~\ref{fig:one} and \subcaptionref{fig:two}.

\end{document}
```

which yields
[image]
but I want
[image]

Is there a way of letting LaTeX position the label where I want it to relative the top left corner of the image? Or at least hide the caption for each individual subfigure while still labelling it?

Comment: Not that I know of, You may have to do this manually, for example using overpic and a counter defined to reset each time `figure` is changed.

Comment: I presume you would still need the ability to `\ref` the subfigures?  Or can that be dispensed with?

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the ability to use both \ref and \subcaptionref

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the `subcaption` package and `\phantomsubcaption` (or `\phantomcaption` if you decide to use e.g., `subfigure` environment). Note that you need version 1.1 of the subcaption package.
Below is your adapted MME:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz,siunitx,mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\newcommand{\scalebarimg}[6]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw node[name=micrograph] {\includegraphics[width=#2\textwidth]{#1}}; %I fetch the image
    \draw[ultra thick,#6] (micrograph.south west)++(0.03*0#2\textwidth,0.035*0#2\textwidth)--++(#2*#3\textwidth,0)node[above,midway]
    {#4 \si{\micro\meter}}; %I draw the scalebar
    \draw  (micrograph.north west)  node[anchor=north west,yshift=-1,#6]{\textbf{\small{#5}}}; %I draw the image label
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
   {\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:one}
   \scalebarimg{example-image}{.45}{0.33933}{50}{\subref{fig:one}}{black}}
   {\phantomsubcaption\label{fig:two}
   \scalebarimg{example-image}{.45}{0.33933}{50}{\subref{fig:two}}{white}}
\caption{Figures (a) and (b) should not be doubly labeled.}
\end{figure}

See Figure~\ref{fig:one} and \subcaptionref{fig:two}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of compilation]

I surrounded each subfigure with just `{}` (needed to separate figure from subfigure) but you can put them for example in `minipage`, `subfigure` etc. If you want to customise label, see `subcaption` documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I see a nice answer has appeared, but since I was working on this one, I'll present it also.  The `\tripleinset` macro has 8 parameters plus an optional parameter.  They are, in order:

"label" - optional parameter, for later use of `\ref`.  The subfigs add an `a`, `b`, and `c` to this label

`\labelhoffset` - the horizontal inset of the label. "0in" would actually be centered over the left margin, but that is shifted to prevent that.

`\labevhoffset` - for the vertical inset of the label. "0in" would actually be centered over the top margin, but that is shifted to prevent that.

`\interfiggap` - the horizontal gap between figures

`\figa` - left most figure

`\figb` - center figure

`\figc` - right most figure

`\figurelableoffset` - the gap between lowest subfigure and caption

"caption" - the caption

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\gapa
\newlength\gapb
\newlength\gapc
\newlength\labelhoffset
\newlength\labelvoffset
\newlength\figlabeloffset
\newlength\vskiplength
\newlength\interfiggap
\newlength\totalheight
\newcommand\tripleinset[9][]{%
  \labelhoffset=#2\relax% cannot exceed 1/2 the figure width or figures shift
  \labelvoffset=#3\relax
  \figlabeloffset=#8\relax
  \interfiggap=#4\relax
  \def\figa{#5}
  \def\figb{#6}
  \def\figc{#7}
  \ifdim\labelvoffset<.5\baselineskip\labelvoffset=.5\baselineskip\relax\fi
  \setbox0=\hbox{\figa}\setlength\gapa{\dimexpr\wd0+\interfiggap-2\labelhoffset\relax}
  \totalheight=\ht0\relax
  \setbox1=\hbox{\figb}\setlength\gapb{\dimexpr\wd1+\interfiggap-2\labelhoffset\relax}
  \ifdim\ht1>\totalheight\totalheight=\ht1\relax\fi
  \setbox2=\hbox{\figc}\setlength\gapc{\dimexpr\wd2-2\labelhoffset\relax}
  \ifdim\ht2>\totalheight\totalheight=\ht2\relax\fi
  \vskiplength=\dimexpr\totalheight-\labelvoffset-\baselineskip+\figlabeloffset\relax
  \savestack{\capfiga}{%
    \subcaptionbox{\label{#1a}}[2\labelhoffset]{\smash{\belowbaseline[\baselineskip-\labelvoffset]{\figa}}}}
  \savestack{\capfigb}{%
    \subcaptionbox{\label{#1b}}[2\labelhoffset]{\smash{\belowbaseline[\baselineskip-\labelvoffset]{\figb}}}}
  \savestack{\capfigc}{%
    \subcaptionbox{\label{#1c}}[2\labelhoffset]{\smash{\belowbaseline[\baselineskip-\labelvoffset]{\figc}}}}
  \vspace{\labelvoffset}
  \capfiga\hspace{\gapa}\capfigb\hspace{\gapb}\capfigc\hspace{\gapc}\vspace{\vskiplength}%
  \caption{#9\label{#1}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\tripleinset[fg:]{0.15in}{0.15in}{0.3in}
  {\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{example-image}}
  {\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{example-image}}
  {\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{example-image}}
  {0.5\baselineskip}{This is my figure}
\end{figure}
\noindent In figure \ref{fg:}, \ref{fg:a}, \ref{fg:b} and \ref{fg:c}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\tripleinset{0.3in}{0.10in}{0.15in}
  {\includegraphics[width=.9in,height=.9in]{example-image}}
  {\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{example-image}}
  {\includegraphics[width=1.1in,height=1.1in]{example-image}}
  {0.2\baselineskip}{This is my other figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice parallel answer to mine, in a sense that it moves caption instead of drawing it in the image. +1

Comment: @Tahtisilma In my case, it is even more subtle.  I move the image to place it under the subcaption label.  and +1 back at you.