# Add text box on top of figure

Tags: graphics

I want to add text labels for each panel of an inserted picture (e.g. A B C).  Each individual figure currently exists as pdf and jpg, but I want to join them together into a single pdf with each panel labeled.  I have searched high and low to figure out how to make text sit atop the image and have gotten nowhere (other than to import the pdf and make a new document).  The end product should look like the image below (taken from web).  I have done this plenty of times in Word, etc., but I would like to further my transition to LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this question might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170720/subfigure-label-position-and-visibility-in-memoir

Comment: You can also use TikZ. I cannot find an exact solution, but I suggest to have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/simplest-way-to-overlay-a-text-rectangle-label-an-image, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz to get started.

Comment: Steven, that worked perfectly (with minor edits).  It is not as intuitive as I had hoped, but that is just a symantecs issue on my part.  This was certainly helpful; thanks.