# How does one get the caption to over-print an image?

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I'm preparing a manuscript for a journal where they tend to have the caption over-print on the image for subfigures to really squeeze out all the whitespace in these panels (Here's an example document, please look at the PDF: https://elifesciences.org/articles/39777).

So, I've been trying to remove whitespaces around my subfigures too. I used a negative skip in the subcaption set up which brings the subcaption nearer to the image. However, when using this "hack", in a majority of cases, the image prints over the label. Is it possible to do it the other way around: get the subcaption label to over-print on the image?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont={bf},labelsep=space,labelformat=simple,font=Large,margin=0pt,skip=-8pt,position=top}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
      \caption{}\label{fig:ex-1}%
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
      \caption{}\label{fig:ex-2}%
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Example figures with negative skip but images over-printing the labels}\label{fig:test-mwe}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: MEW screenshot]

Comment: Duplicate?? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170720/subfigure-label-position-and-visibility-in-memoir

Comment: Related, rather. I already thought about hardcoding labels using tikz on to the images, but that is a very tedious way of going about it. I was really hoping that there'd be a simpler way using the provided captioning commands.

Edit: A lot of the figures are epslatex outputs from Gnuplot, which will make using the Tikz method even more complex. I could just hardcode the labels in the Gnuplot generated `.tex` files here if that is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the subcaption after the `\includegraphics` with a negative skip and add a positive skip automatically at the end of `subfigure` environment with `\AtEndEnvironment` by `etoolbox`.

In the MWE the float is still too long for the page, but you will adjust it with your actual images.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont={bf},labelsep=space,labelformat=simple,font=Large,margin=0pt,skip=-55ex,position=bottom}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{subfigure}{\vspace{50ex}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!t]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{}\label{fig:ex-1}%
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{}\label{fig:ex-2}%
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Example figures with negative skip but images over-printing the labels}\label{fig:test-mwe}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]